# How can I use bullets and Numbering in Notepad++?

Tags: editor, text-editor, notepad++

Is there a way I can have bullets and numbering in Notepadd++ for lists.

Comment: Notepad++ is a plain-text editor. You don't have access to the same formatting tools that you would in, say, Microsoft Word.

Comment: Just a small shout out -- you _can_ actually do this in emacs with org-mode.

Comment: I understand its just a text editor. Is there a way I can make Notepad++ to start a numbered list so I dont need to enter it.

Comment: This is a valid question. Numbered and bulleted lists can be manually represented as ASCII text. user44556's comment on the answer below shows one way to do it after the items in the list have been typed (see the youtube video).  It involves two calls to the Column Editor feature.  A plugin could make this a lot easier.

Comment: Why so many upvotes for Michael's comment, which is absolutely off base. Notepad++ has a ton of formatting features that Word doesn't have.

Comment: That's the great thing about SO - you can upvote but not downvote - some clowns blindly like to vote for Windows Word or the first thing they are thinking of too. Plenty who follow are going to be wrongly advised because of this.

Comment: @Zoomzoom You misunderstood the comment. Michael did not say it has no such features; he said they are different features. And, because Notepad++ is a _text_ editor, he is correct.

Comment: @killjoy The actual problem there is people writing answers in the comments section, which is not designed for that. Answers can be upvoted _and_ downvoted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Notepad++ is just a text editor. As long as no-one implements a custom plugin that takes advantage of special unicode characters looking like bullets, you probably need to stick with "-" and "1)" kind of syntax.

Comment: Look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1p7rMCGt_30 The trick showed between 20-40s can be applied to normal text. Does that help you?

Comment: Thanks for the youtube tricks, so in plain text, what you do is to press "Alt+C" to enable column mode, and a popup dialog shows. From there, you can set the starting number and increment value to insert the bullet numbers at the front of the selected lines.

Comment: To summarize all of the above: Select the text, press Alt+C, then Alt+NumPad's 7, add a space after, click OK. Works like a charm.

Comment: In version 8.5.3 of Notepad++ Column mode settings apply to all the lines _under_ where the cursor currently is. So if you want to apply it to a selection, the selection needs to be at the bottom of the file. I move the selected text to the bottom of the file to apply the change and then move it back to its original location.

Answer (score 34):

Notepad++ doesn't support this, as it is a *text* editor. However, on Windows we have ["Alt codes"](https://www.alt-codes.net/) for all text fields, and the text field in Notepad++ is no exception. The "Alt code" for a bullet point is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>. Make sure you use the number pad.

Alternatively, just write a nice ASCII hyphen. Your text file's readers will thank you!

Indentation can be done with just tabs or Edit->Indent menu

Comment: For anyone else, you use the number pad.  Not unique to Notepad++, Alt+### will give you ASCII characters. Helpful though!

Comment: Yeah but the bullets are line by line, when we choose a block it just replaces entire block with a bullet.

Comment: does not work.....

Comment: @killjoy Because, from Notepad++'s perspective, you are just entering a character. This is not a Notepad++ formatting feature. Notepad++ is a text editor, not a word processor.

Comment: Alt+7 worked. Thank you.